Movie where three teen girls sneak into house and kill a man by pushing him down the stairs?
I can't find it anywhere. These three college girls are on winter break and one of them suggests they head to her uncle's house/mansion as he is away. They have a good time, but then a man (I think its the maintenance guy) shows up and is chasing them or something, but one of the girls pushes him down the stairs. I think he becomes paralyzed and you find out its not the girl's uncle's like she previously said. Anyway the rest of the film they're trying to figure out what to do with the man and they end up arguing and fighting because they want to do different things. I don't know, very suspenseful.
I want to say it was pretty recent. Probably 2012-2015. The girls were American, they spoke English. None of the actresses are necessarily mainstream but their characters were like this: one was a pretty, popular girl, one was more reserved and I guess you would say "nerdy" and she also had an ex boyfriend trying to get back together with her, and the third girl was chill and very neutral.

Hi. Do you remember the approximate year of release? The country\language? Any of the actresses or what they looked like?

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Thanks for adding more details. Posted a possible match.

Sounds like Body from 2015.

It's a couple nights before Christmas and the three girls are bored out of their minds, sitting at Mel's parents house. As she is wont to do, Cali suggests they go out and have some fun. Her uncle owns a mansion one town over and happens to be out of town for the holiday. Better yet, he's given her permission to party there. Despite Holly's reservations, the girls head out. It's only after hours of partying and taking advantage of the home's many amenities that the girls discover Cali has lied to them. This is not her uncle's house. It belongs to a family that Cali used to babysit for. And it becomes quite clear that permission was certainly never granted to party there. Holly and Mel, infuriated with Cali, immediately head for the door. Unfortunately, before they can leave, the groundskeeper of the estate arrives. The girls attempt to flee, but wind up running into him on their way out. An altercation follows and in a freak accident, the girls push him down the stairs. He falls awkwardly, breaking his neck and ultimately dying. For the remainder of the film, we watch the girls slowly unravel as they decide what to do about the dead body in the living room. But covering their tracks might mean adding to the body count...

Here's the trailer:



